# WCF Salesforce SOAP Client switch endpoint

Tags: soap-api, webservices, c#, login

Is there a way to switch WCF client endpoint address after **login** call?
I don't use app.config file:

`var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
 var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(
 @"https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/36.0");
 SoapClient client = new SoapClient(binding, addressSoap);`

After successful login I need to switch endpoint to the correct server url

Is there a better way to do that except:

`endpoint = new EndpointAddress(loginResponse.result.serverUrl);
 client = new SoapClient(binding, endpoint);`

Answer (score 1):

The alternative way to change the ClientBase Endpoint is to directly reassign the Endpoint.
E.g.

```
SoapClient client = new SoapClient(binding, addressSoap);
SalesforcePartner.LoginResult loginResult = await partnerApi.loginAsync("user@example.com", "password" + "securityToken");
client.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(loginResult.serverUrl);
```

**However, that doesn't actually work** once the client has been "opened". Once `OpenAsync()` has been called internally the client channel gets locked into the endpoint that was set when it was created.

It's far easier to just recreate the new SoapClient for the new `serverUrl` endpoint as you have done and then add the Endpoint Behavior for the session id header.